# JavaScript - transform this data structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

When I have this array with this data structure:

```
[[3, 16, 1]
[3, 17, 1]
[3, 18, 1]
[3, 19, 1]
[3, 20, 1]
[3, 19, 1]
[3, 21, 1]
[3, 23, 1]
[3, 16, 1]
[3, 17, 1]
[2, 24, 1]
[2, 25, 1]
[2, 26, 1]
[2, 24, 1]]
```

and I want to count array elements and multiply this to the last number of the array, like this:

```
[[3, 16, 2]
[3, 17, 2]
[3, 18, 1]
[3, 19, 2]
[3, 20, 1]
[3, 21, 1]
[3, 23, 1]
[2, 24, 2]
[2, 25, 1]
[2, 26, 1]]
```

I tried to do it with:

```
array.forEach(function(x) { 
    
    counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0)+1; 
    
});
```

but this changes the data structure, **is there another form to do it?**

Comment: It is not clear what the question is doing. [3,16,1] and [3,16,2] both appear in the output array.

Comment: sorry, i change data output and delete [3,16,1] . I just want to count the equal arrays and multiply it by its last value.  there are two arrays  [3,16,1] , and for this reason i multiply by 2 [3,16, 1 * 2] .

Comment: Not sure what your ```counts``` function is, so I write my own function for your quesiton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrite your function and console.log the output you want.
Whenever I check a new array, I store it in checkedArr and will check against it to prevent duplicate records.

```js
const arr = [
  [3, 16, 1],
  [3, 17, 1],
  [3, 18, 1],
  [3, 19, 1],
  [3, 20, 1],
  [3, 19, 1],
  [3, 21, 1],
  [3, 23, 1],
  [3, 16, 1],
  [3, 17, 1],
  [2, 24, 1],
  [2, 25, 1],
  [2, 26, 1],
  [2, 24, 1],
];

const checkedArr = [];
const output = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  let count = 0;
  if (!isArrayChecked(arr[i])) {
    checkedArr.push(arr[i]);
    for (let j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (isArraySame(arr[i], arr[j])) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    output.push([arr[i][0], arr[i][1], count]);
  }
}

function isArrayChecked(array) {
  let exist = false;
  for (let k = 0; k < checkedArr.length; k++) {
    if (isArraySame(array, checkedArr[k])) {
      exist = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return exist;
}

function isArraySame(arr1, arr2) {
  if (arr1[0] !== arr2[0] || arr1[1] !== arr2[1] || arr1[2] !== arr2[2])
    return false;
  return true;
}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is in `counts[x]`. You can't use an array to index an object.

You can solve the issue by stringifying the array. That is, use:

```
counts[String(x)] = (counts[String(x)] || 0)+1;
```

Comment: but this give an object, like this { 3, 16, 1: 2 ,
3, 17, 1 : 2,
3, 18, 1 : 1,
3, 19, 1 : 2 ,
3, 20, 1:  1,
3, 21, 1 : 1 ,
3, 23, 1 : 1, 
2, 24, 1 : 2,
2, 25, 1 : 1,
2, 26, 1 : 1 }. not an array of arrays .

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let arr=[
     [3, 16, 1],
    [3, 17, 1],
    [3, 18, 1],
    [3,16,1],
    [3, 19, 1],
    [3, 20, 1],
    [3, 19, 1],
    [3, 21, 1],
    [3, 23, 1],
    [3, 16, 1],
    [3, 17, 1],
    [2, 24, 1],
    [2, 25, 1],
    [2, 26, 1],
    [2, 24, 1]]

    let solution = (arr) => {
      let obj = {};
      let result = [];
      for (let i of arr) {
        let keyOfObj = JSON.stringify(i);
        obj[keyOfObj] ? obj[keyOfObj]++ : obj[keyOfObj] = 1;
      }
      for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        let objKeyArr = JSON.parse(key);
        if (value >= 2) {
          let lastElemt = objKeyArr[objKeyArr.length - 1];
          objKeyArr.splice(objKeyArr.length - 1, 1, lastElemt * value);
          result.push(objKeyArr);
        } else {
          result.push(objKeyArr);
        }
      }
      return result;
    };
  solution(arr)
```